# Laravel on shared hosting - subdomain

Tags: php, laravel, deployment, subdomain, shared-hosting

I am trying to deploy my laravel application on a shared hosting. It should be deployed in www.subdomain.something.com

My folder structure is:

```
    /laravel
       app/
       vendor/
       bootstrap/
       server.php
       artisan
       composer.json
       composer.lock
       phpunit.xml
   /public_html
       subdomain/
       index.php
```

My index.php have the following paths:

```
require '/../../laravel/bootstrap/autoload.php';
$app = require_once '/../../laravel/bootstrap/start.php';
```

My paths.php

```
'app' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel/app',
'public' => __DIR__.'/../../public_html/subdomain',
'base' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel',
'storage' => __DIR__.'/../../laravel/app/storage',
```

Can anyone see what I am missing? I tried google, and found a bunch of step-by-step explanations but nothing seems to work - It results in a 500 internal server error.

Thanks for any feedback

Wesley

Comment: Have you mapped the subdomain's document root to Laravel's `public` directory?

Comment: I don't have a public directory anymore, the content of the public directory is now directly in public_html/subdomain

My apologies if I'm not making sense, I don't have that much experience deploying on a shared host...

Comment: You're making perfect sense. It was my mistake to call it `public`, I should have said `public_html/subdomain`. But the question is the same, is the document root for the subdomain pointing to that directory? If that's something you don't know how to configure, it might help if you specified what hosting company your are using.

Comment: After a lot of searching I've switched from using a shared hosting to an Apache on a virtual server that I have in the cloud. Everything seems to work now...
Thanks for the advice anyhow though!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the first rule [here](http://blog.netgloo.com/2016/01/29/deploy-laravel-application-on-shared-hosting/).
If you use the first rule then everything should work fine. But somehow if you face `500 Internal Server Error` then login to ur server `public_html` directory through `ssh` and give the following command.

`sudo chmod 755 -R laravel`

`chmod -R o+w laravel/storage`

Here `laravel` is your Laravel project directory.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have write permissions to `app/storage/` and all the sub directories. This sounds like the culprit but if not then see if you get any errors in the `app/storage/logs` dir. If not see if you can parse the server logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problem and found the solution.Maybe someone can get help with this,

[Install LARAVEL 5 Locally Same as Share Hosting Directory (Deploy L5 Share Hosting Solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33690681/install-laravel-5-locally-same-as-share-hosting-directory)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to deploy my first Laravel 8 application on shared hosting on DreamHost, and did encounter some issues.

1. First I was not able to use composer. Composer 1 was available however, I was unable to upgrade it to Composer 2. ( Was getting errors)
2. Finally, I ended up uploading all files from my local system to the subdomain root folder (e.g. cota.mydomain.com)
3. When I tried **cota.mydomain.com**, I got 404 error.
4. When I changed url to **cota.mydomain.com/public/index.php**, the application started working. However, all href links which were defined like href="/home" or **href="/client/create"** started giving 'not found' errors. To fix this issue I had to use named routes in href, e.g. **href=" {{ route('client.show',['id'=>$client->id]) }}"**. This solved the issue, however, the URL displayed included public/index.php, e.g.  **cota.mydomain.com/public/index.php/client/show/1**.
5. To further fix the problem, I changed the web folder (root folder) for my subdomain to include public, i.e. cota.mydomain.com/public
6. Next I added an index.php in cota.mydomain.con with the following contents
   `header("Location: http://www.cota.mydomain.com/public/index.php"); die();`
7. This fixed all issues, including remving public and index.php from link URLs.